# Autostrat of jwplayer doesn't works

Tags: jquery, video, jwplayer

I have such jwplayer video on my page:

```
                    jwp=jwplayer('video').setup({ 
                        file: '/assets/video/video.mp4', 
                        height: 480,
                        width: 640, 
                        autostart: true
                    });
```

As it said [here](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428525-autostarting-on-page-load) it should start, when Page loads. When I run it on Ipad it doesn't starts automatically, but I can run it by clicking play button. It is not on page actually, it is in tab of tabbed pane. Can this be problem?

Comment: Note that autostarting does not work on mobile phones (Android, iOS), since a fullscreen video takeover would be a jarring experience. Video also swiftly depletes 3G/4G bandwidth allowances.

Comment: Devices disable autostart in html5 <video> natively.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that autostart does not work on mobile device

from docs

Comment: To clarify: this is not a limitation of JW Player. No matter what video player script you use, autostart can't be invoked on a mobile device - it's blocked by the device's own operating system.

Comment: Devices disable autostart in html5 <video> natively.